# How to see logarithm of a number from Chamber's log table of 7 figures?

Tags: logarithms

all I'm studying logarithm from SL. Loney's plane trigonometry. I just don't understand how to use Chamber's log table which is provided at the end of the book. I knew how to find **logarithm** of a number such as 2345 where I've to use only one number under the mean difference 5. But I'm not certain about how to find the **logarithm** of a number such as 23456 where I need to use two numbers under the mean difference column 5 and 6 respectively.
Any help will be vere very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, if the mean difference for 5 was x for example, then you may approximate the mean difference for 0.6 as x/50 * 6

Does this answer your question?